# Spark - groupByKey other options

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

We have a need to control huge dataset using Spark. The control consists of grouping the data by key (we use for this : `groupByKey()`) and then looping for each grouped data to check coherence between them.

For example we have the below csv file contains these columns to check :

```
id;dateBegin;dateEnd;event;dateEvent
1;12/02/2015;30/05/2015;active;05/04/2015
1;12/06/2015;30/07/2015;dead;05/07/2015
2;12/02/2016;30/07/2016;dead;05/04/2015
```

We used `JavaRdd<String>.map().groupByKey()` but Spark freezes for large dataset.

Are there other options to use? 
Thank you

Comment: I'd recommend explaining _check coherence_ parts, optimally with the relevant code. Without that, it is unlikely someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

According to this documentation: [Avoid GroupByKey](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html)

> **reduceByKey()** is good for larger data sets as, Spark (before shuffling data) can combine the output with a common key. But, **groupByKey()** shuffles the data (k-v pairs) creating unnecessary data sets.

Look for better (other) alternatives to `groupByKey`. Like,

- combineByKey
- foldByKey